# Automatic Table of Contents in MS Word 2007 adds unnecessary numbers

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, table-of-contents

I created an automatic Table of Contents in Word 2007, and lo and behold, it adds some unnecessary numbers to level-1 lines:

> [image]

I can manually delete those numbers and bring the ToC to a normal appearance:

> [image]

But that is quite tedious. I have a similar document where no problem of this kind arises. Why does it arise and what do I do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: one needs to select the entire ToC, press the right mouse button and select "Numeration" in the right-button menu, then choose "no numeration".

I haven't understood yet why MS Word enabled numeration by default in this particular case, but at least I found an easy solution.